# Default emoji button in google keyboard with android 4.4

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, ime, android-4.4-kitkat

When using google keyboard in android 4.4 (or installing his keyboard version in previous android versions), using the default SMS app or in hangouts, the "enter button" is replaced by default for a emoji button, like this:

[image]

However, in my app, when typing on a EditText, I have to long click the default enter button to see the emoji option. I wonder.. is there any option to make emoji the default button?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Found it!

android:inputType="textShortMessage"

Comment: But in some devices, this smiley key is not visible. Especially in some Samsung and xperia devices. Is there a way to handle it?

Comment: personally I like cap sentences so, android:inputType="textCapSentences|textShortMessage"